# Add a line to an existing text file?

Tags: powershell

I am using the code below but it seems to replace all the lines of the file instead of just inserting it on line 4 and deletes the rest. Is there a way to just insert a line into this text file at a specific position?

```
$Properties = "C:\Temp\Test.txt"
$fileContent = Get-Content $Properties | Select -Index 4
$lineNumber = "4"
$textToAdd = "Test"
$fileContent[$lineNumber] += $textToAdd
$fileContent | Set-Content $Properties
```

Comment: `Set-Content` -> `Add-Content`

Comment: I get this error now Unable to index into an object of type System.String.
+ $fileContent[$lineNumber] += $textToAdd

Comment: That's because you've added `|Select -Index 4`

Comment: ok when I take that away it copies the entire file contents again into the file. So there are 8 lines in the file and then it repeats another 8 lines again. And "Test" is not on  its own line. Its just at the end of the existing string on line 4

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show sample input as well the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to add a line of text to an existing file:

```
"new line of text" |Add-Content -Path .\path\to\file.txt
```

If you want to append something to a specific line in the middle of the file:

```
# read all lines into `$fileContents`
$filePath = "C:\Temp\Test.txt"
$fileContents = Get-Content $filePath 

# append text to desired line
$lineNumber = "4"
$textToAdd = "Test"
$fileContents[$lineNumber] += $textToAdd

# write all lines back to file
$fileContents | Set-Content $filePath
```

Comment: Thank you, I get this error on $properties set-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null. Also, set-content seems to duplicate the entire contents at the end of the file